# Write ICriteria for CONTAINSTABLE (sql fulltext search)

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, full-text-search, criteria

I need to do fulltext search over multiple tables, so i use SqlServer CONTAINSTABLE function, it works fine as a SQL query, but how can i **rewrite CONTAINSTABLE into NHibernate ICriteria.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CP.* FROM ContentPack CP
    INNER JOIN [Content] C ON CP.ContentPackId = C.ContentPackId

 INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE([Content], (Title, [Description]), 'Foo*') AS KEY_TBL
     ON C.Title = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

I need to **convert this SQL to NHibernate Criteria**, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5):

The same problem which i also got

[NHibernate + SqlServer full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076121/nhibernate-sqlserver-full-text-search)

and i didn't got any solution so i went for interceptor concept where

1)I created detached criteria for main table and joined the full text table

2)Also created a custom interceptor for nhibernate which will replace full text table name with    `(select [key] as foreignkey,[rank] as rank FROM CONTAINSTABLE(full_text,full_text_col , 'Foo*'))`

### Code

*Generated query*

```
SELECT c.id,
        c.name,
        ft.id, 
        ft.rank 
FROM candidates c 
    INNER JOIN full_text ft ON ft.id  = c.fulltext_id 
ORDER BY rank
```

*Query after interception*

```
SELECT c.id,
        c.name,
        ft.id,
        ft.rank 
FROM candidates c 
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [KEY] AS id ,[rank] AS rank 
            FROM CONTAINSTABLE(full_text, full_text_col, 'Foo*')
               ) AS ft ON ft.id  = c.fulltext_id 
ORDER BY rank
```

****DetachedCriteria ****

```
        DetachedCriteria candidateCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Candidate>();
        DetachedCriteria fullTextCriteria = candidateCriteria.CreateCriteria("FullText");
```

**Interceptor code**

```
public interface CustomInterceptor : IInterceptor, EmptyInterceptor
{
    private string fulltextString;
    public string FulltextString
    {
        get { return fulltextString; }
        set { fulltextString = value; }
    }
    SqlString IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        string query = sql.ToString();
        if (query.Contains("full_text"))
        {
            sql = sql.Replace("full_text", "(select [key] as foreignkey,[rank] as Rank FROM CONTAINSTABLE(full_text, full_text_col, '"+FulltextString+"')) AS ft'");
        }
        return sql;
    }
}
```

Entity

**candidtes table**

id int

name string

fulltext_id

**full_text table contains full text index**

id int

full_text_col text

rank int //always null

**Relation**

Candidate - FullText (1-1)

**OpenSession**

```
CustomInterceptor custonInterceptor=new CustomInterceptor();
custonInterceptor.FulltextString="YourString";
sessionFactory.OpenSession(custonInterceptor);
```

Comment: @chuck-see edited code-at present i don't have exact code(which is in office) any way this method is an exact solution its a hack

Comment: I have a lot of tables where I search using fulltext, and sometimes I search into multiple tables at once (join), should I do a dummy table /interceptor for each table where I have to search ?

Comment: no you have to use only one dummy table for fulltext result return value.ie (full_text
id int
key int)which table always contain no value and add an entity FullText with properties of Id and Key

Comment: this dummy table has to have a foreign key to each table where I do search (I see you have "candidate_Id") ?

Comment: @ChuckNorris-Here i shared the doc which contains query of actual nhibernate generated query and query edited by interceptor.I think by looking this query you may get some idea.Also i specified schema for two table (main table which will be joined to multiple table and full text table where i configured full text index).And with this you can search multiple table  at once(join) bcoz same thing im doing.Check the link  http://www.box.com/s/7if894sr9piz41go7ctz

Comment: Your example is good, but is SQL Injection Attacks vulnerable.

Comment: I am processing the full text string before executing the query for some sql server requirements like remove sql noise words and some alignment blah..blah..So 0% possibility of sql injection

Answer (score 2):

You can use named queries

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/04/16/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-lt-query-gt-and-lt-sql-query-gt.html

```
<sql-query name="MyQuery">
    <return alias="cp"
                    class="ContentPack"/>
    SELECT DISTINCT {cp.*}
    INNER JOIN [Content] C ON CP.ContentPackId = C.ContentPackId
    INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE([Content], (Title, [Description]), 'Foo*') AS KEY_TBL
     ON C.Title = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
</sql-query>
```

Comment: I need to do this using ICriteria not SQL

Comment: The criteria API only allows you to use your entities in your joins. You can't specify a table valued function as a source for an entity. Hence, it is not supported. You can try the other solution using Interceptors, but it's unlikely to be very stable imo.